# How should i structure multiple redirects and return views in a single controller function?

Tags: php, laravel

Just a bit of backstory on what I'm currently doing and trying to achieve.

I've decided to [follow this](https://m.dotdev.co/design-pattern-service-layer-with-laravel-5-740ff0a7b65f) design pattern for development as my controllers are getting ridiculously huge. As a result, I've now built repositories and services which handle all of my logic. My controllers are super lightweight now.

Why? Because right now I'm focusing fully on the functionality of the website and using a basic web bootstrap front-end. Then later, when I start learning React/Vue, I can easily leverage the same services and repositories to create my API layer and slowly develop a separated front-end.

I managed to get a lot of my functionality moved into my services however one aspect of my project is proving problematic and I don't quite know how best to approach this to refactor. Let me start with a sample function:

```
public function index()
{
    //Returns all of the clubs a user is a part of
    $userClubs = auth()->user()->clubs;

    //Returns if a user is a chairman or not
    $chairman  = auth()->user()->chairman;

    switch ($userClubs->count()) {

        //If a user is part of NO clubs but is a chairman, redirect to /chairman, else, redirect to /
        case 0:
            return ($chairman == 1 ? redirect('/chairman') : redirect('/'));
            break;

        //If a user is part of 1 club and IS a chairman, show the select-club view, else take the user directly to the single club they are a part of
        case 1:
            if ($chairman == 1){
                return view('club.select-club', ['clubs' => $userClubs]);
            }
            if ($userClubs->first()->pivot->verified == 1){
                return redirect('/club/'.$userClubs->first()->url_extension);
            }
            return redirect('/user')->with('message', 'Your account for '. $userClubs->first()->club_name .' has not been verified. Please try again later.');
            break;

        //If a user is part of multiple clubs, show the select-club view
        default:
            return view('club.select-club', ['clubs' => $userClubs]);
            break;
    }
}
```

I've added inline comments to the above code block.

How can I move this functionality out of my controller and into my services?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: then just create a method in your service and pass two arguments i.e page name and data. Then view it from the service.php or pass all the parameters which you check here to service and filter data and page there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a __construct() to your controller :

```
/**
 * Construct
 * @param DispatchService $dispatchService
 */
public function __construct(DispatchService $dispatchService) {
    $this->dispatchService = $dispatchService;
}
```

Then call this in your index() method :

```
public function index() {
    //Call the dispatchService
    return $this->dispatchService->dispatchUsers(auth()->user);
}
```

Moove the logic to the newly created DispatchService.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail as to how I would structure my dispatch service? For example, how would I handle the multiple return types (return redirect and return view).

Comment: You can structure it like you want since you return what you were returning previously it will work